# Environment Variable set in .bashrc file visible in terminal but not through Python program

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables

I have set the environment variable for one of my API keys in Ubuntu. For that I used the way to set it through using `.bashrc` file and `export` statement. Till now, everything is working fine and when I type `env` command in terminal, it shows the environment variable from which I may conclude that the variable has been set successfully.

But when I try to access it in the Python by OS module, I am not able to see that environment variable.

**Code**:

```
import os

    print("Environment Variable Keys: ")
    print("---------------------------")
    env_keys = list(os.environ.keys())
    env_keys.sort()
    for key in env_keys:
        print(key)
```

For simplicity,I have converted keys into list and have sorted them.

Why I am not able to see the required variable? ( Other env variables are being shown by python but not the one set by me)

Comment: How are you running the python script? Is it a subprocess of a shell that has the environment variable set, or run in some other way?

Comment: No I launched it from GUI

Comment: That's the reason, then. Processes inherit the environment of the parent process that forked them, and .bashrc is only loaded by bash shells (and then only interactive, non-login ones). So if the script isn't a child (or descendent) of an interactive bash shell, it won't get a copy of that variable.

Comment: Great. Now when I run the same Python script as a standalone script from terminal, I am able to get the environment variable there. As in this case, the script was being executed directly from the terminal.

Comment: You can probably find a way to set the same variable in your GUI, but that depends on which GUI. On MacOS, probably add settings to a `.plist` somewhere; for many others, have your desktop's startup script source a file which you also source from your `.bashrc`.

Comment: BTW, is there any way, I can set environment variable which I can literally access anywhere on the system irrespective of whether my process has forked from its parent process or not?

Comment: @stardep put it in a `.py` file and import it like a regular file ? Like so `MY_API_KEY="aBcDeF0#"` then `from api_key_file import MY_API_KEY`. You *just* have to make the import work now. But this becomes another question, for which you should ask on a new page.